# How to reinstall server

Tags: installation, server, raid, iscsi

Since I got a blank screen after installation, I tried to reinstall the server OS 12.04 using the CD.

This time after the country and login information are given, it asks me to specify some scsi settings. I don't recall doing any such thing. What can this be? Without doing this step, it says that there's no root. I've got 2 HDDs and I initially specified them as RAID during the last installation.

I think I've messed up the settings and I just want to reinstall the whole thing afresh. Any ideas please...

Comment: This is not an answer, but I am having the same problem as the OP. >
>3.In the terminal, type: sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1M count=8 && sync
>4.And then type: sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1M count=8 && sync It appears steps 3 and 4 are the same, is this a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

> **Warning:** this will completely wipe your hard drives

1. Boot from the Ubuntu Installer/Live CD, and choose "Try Ubuntu..."
2. At the Live Desktop, press `Ctrl-Alt-T` to open a terminal.
3. In the terminal, type: `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1M count=8 && sync`
4. And then type:  `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1M count=8 && sync`
5. Shut-down the LiveCD.
6. Insert the Server CD and start installation.

> Note: *If your computer is very old and uses IDE cables for the hard drives (wide connector), you may have to use `hda` instead of `sda`

Comment: thank you for your inputs but I don't have a try option. It's the Ubuntu server without a desktop.